# Image data of dtype <U54 cannot be converted to float

Tags: python

I have an error on my image, but don't know how to solve. Can anyone please help me with that?

Error:

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3929 entries, 0 to 3928
Data columns (total 4 columns):

## Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   patient_id  3929 non-null   object
1   image_path  3929 non-null   object
2   mask_path   3929 non-null   object
3   mask        3929 non-null   int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 122.9+ KB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3929 entries, 0 to 3928
Data columns (total 4 columns):

## Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   patient_id  3929 non-null   object
1   image_path  3929 non-null   object
2   mask_path   3929 non-null   object
3   mask        3929 non-null   int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 122.9+ KB
patient_id  ... mask
0     TCGA_CS_5395_19981004  ...    0
1     TCGA_CS_5395_19981004  ...    0
2     TCGA_CS_5395_19981004  ...    0
3     TCGA_CS_5395_19981004  ...    0
4     TCGA_CS_5395_19981004  ...    0
...                     ...  ...  ...
3924  TCGA_DU_6401_19831001  ...    0
3925  TCGA_DU_6401_19831001  ...    0
3926  TCGA_DU_6401_19831001  ...    0
3927  TCGA_DU_6401_19831001  ...    0
3928  TCGA_DU_6401_19831001  ...    0

[3929 rows x 4 columns]
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
0       TCGA_CS_5395_19981004/TCGA_CS_5395_19981004_1_...
1       TCGA_CS_4944_20010208/TCGA_CS_4944_20010208_1_...
2       TCGA_CS_4941_19960909/TCGA_CS_4941_19960909_1_...
3       TCGA_CS_4943_20000902/TCGA_CS_4943_20000902_1_...
4       TCGA_CS_5396_20010302/TCGA_CS_5396_20010302_1_...
...
3924    TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127/TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127_86...
3925    TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127/TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127_87...
3926    TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127/TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127_87...
3927    TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127/TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127_88...
3928    TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127/TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127_88...
Name: mask_path, Length: 3929, dtype: object
0       TCGA_CS_5395_19981004/TCGA_CS_5395_19981004_1.tif
1       TCGA_CS_4944_20010208/TCGA_CS_4944_20010208_1.tif
2       TCGA_CS_4941_19960909/TCGA_CS_4941_19960909_1.tif
3       TCGA_CS_4943_20000902/TCGA_CS_4943_20000902_1.tif
4       TCGA_CS_5396_20010302/TCGA_CS_5396_20010302_1.tif
...
3924    TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127/TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127_86...
3925    TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127/TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127_87...
3926    TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127/TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127_87...
3927    TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127/TCGA_HT_A61A_20000127_88...
3928    TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127/TCGA_HT_A61B_19991127_88...
Name: image_path, Length: 3929, dtype: object

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\STUDIES\AI MASTER CLASS\P96-Section-3-Healthcare-AI\healthcare_ai.py", line 119, in 
plt.imshow(cv2.imread(brain_df.mask_path[623]))
File "C:\Users\lahoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2730, in imshow
**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lahoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 1447, in inner
return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lahoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 5523, in imshow
im.set_data(X)
File "C:\Users\lahoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 703, in set_data
"float".format(self._A.dtype))
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Code:

## Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import zipfile
import cv2
from skimage import io
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from IPython.display import display
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, normalize
import os
import glob
import random

brain_df = pd.read_csv('./Healthcare+AI+Datasets/Healthcare AI Datasets/Brain_MRI/data_mask.csv')



brain_df.info()

brain_df.head(50)

brain_df.mask_path[1] # Path to the brain MRI image

brain_df.image_path[1] # Path to the segmentation mask



brain_df

brain_df['mask'].value_counts().index

# Use plotly to plot interactive bar chart
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x = brain_df['mask'].value_counts().index, y = brain_df['mask'].value_counts())])
fig.update_traces(marker_color = 'rgb(0,200,0)', marker_line_color = 'rgb(0,255,0)',
                  marker_line_width = 7, opacity = 0.6)
fig.show()


brain_df.info()

brain_df.head(50)

brain_df.mask_path[1]
brain_df.image_path[1]
print(brain_df)
print(brain_df['mask'].value_counts().index)
# Use plotly to plot interactive bar chart
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x = brain_df['mask'].value_counts().index, y = brain_df['mask'].value_counts())])
fig.update_traces(marker_color = 'rgb(0,200,0)', marker_line_color = 'rgb(0,255,0)',
                  marker_line_width = 7, opacity = 0.6)
fig.show()
print(brain_df.mask_path)
print(brain_df.image_path)

plt.imshow(cv2.imread(brain_df.mask_path[623]))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include your code and any error tracebacks as text and not as an image.

Comment: Ok sure I did fix it

Comment: Please include what is printed out before the error.

Comment: Ok sure. I did fix it. Thank you